# Difference between “find by” and “find for”

Tags: differences, programming

In programming exists the so-called repository pattern which is meant to retrieve data from somewhere. It usually has some methods with which it is possible to retrieve that data. These methods are commonly following naming schemes like `find_by_*` or `find_for_*`.

What exactly is the difference between *by* and *for* if used like this?

---

I am extending the question since it seems that this is not detailed enough and people believe that it is not a question about the English language. Consider the following two sentences:

1. “Please, find the record *by* this.”
2. “Please, find the record *for* this.”

Translating this to German (my native tongue) gives me the following:

1. „Bitte finden Sie den Datensatz *damit*.”
2. „Bitte finden Sie den Datensatz *dafür*.”

Judging from the difference in the translation it seems as if the difference could be explained as follows:

1. I have a different, related record, please use this to find the corresponding record(s).
2. I have something that identifies the record, please use it to find the corresponding record(s).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about vocabulary used in programming.

Comment: Ask the programmer who wrote them, or read the documentation, which might be in `/* comments */`. There is no requirement for function names in computer languages to be proper English.

Comment: The question is not about the difference between what the methods do, the question is what difference I communicate to the reader by using either _by_ or _for_.

Comment: I extended the question and hope that it is clearer that it about English and not programming.

Comment: The construction of your first #1 is a little odd in natural English (as opposed to a programming language with English keywords). It could be understood as a request to use *this* to aid in the search (e.g. *by sorting first*, or *by random sampling*). In natural English, *by this* could possibly be coerced to mean *next to this* (e.g. *find the record by the bookshelf*). Your original #2 is a request to find the record that 'corresponds' to *this* (compare: *find the book for this student*, or *find the food for the cat*).

Comment: The _find the record by the bookshelf_ example would mean that it is actually wrong to construct a sentence with _by_ in the context of mine and _for_ is always the correct one. Like “Image repository find the image by ID.” vs “Image repository find the image for ID.”.

Comment: The confusing part of your extension is that your meanings seem to be reversed with regards to my understanding of technical communication, because a record is a collection.

Comment: I think the meaning of record is very specific: “A set of data relating to a single individual or item.” https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/record#Noun

Comment: _By_ here may mean _using_ (i.e., I give you an input, such as an ID; use that input to find a record), and _for_ may mean _corresponding to_ (i.e., I give you an input, such as an ID; find any record[s] that correspond to that value). But both can have other meanings. In normal English (by which I mean non-programming English) neither has any meaning.

Comment: So it would match 1:1 the German meaning of the translations and my German intuitive interpretation would be correct. I’d like that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an English Language usage question.

But you're in luck! Because I am a writer and a Software Engineer so I shall elaborate upon my answer.

In programming, though i don't know which framework you are talking about, my guess is that "by" indicates a single value, while "for" indicates multiple values (i.e. a loop).

For instance, The Fibonacci sequence is a series of numbers where a number is found by adding up the two numbers before it. Starting with 0 and 1, the sequence goes 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, and so forth. To represent such a sequence inside a computer in tiny lightning bolts on a sheet of glass we call that a collection. We use for loops to iterate collections and print them out, or perform operations on them.

It is notable specifically that the keyword "for" is used internationally in a great many programming languages. Other terms include "while", and "do while", which are similar constructs used to iterate collections, which are essentially lists of things.

To summarize my response to the original question and hopefully translate the above, valid, Technical Writing into more formidable American English:

1. By: one item (i.e. 3)
2. For: a collection of items (i.e. 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)

Of course to further complicate things, each item in the list above may also represent a collection, or an even more complex object, such as a corvette. In my answer I have chosen simple primative integer values in hopes of illuminating my point. Thank you for asking, please let me know if i have missed the point entirely. It sounds as as though you are talking about a specific data scenario. I shall reread the question and I appreciate your taking the time to edit.

While I maintain my opinion that this is not an English Language question, I actually believe it is an important valid piece of technical writing, which is valid English ironically.

To support my claim that the English language is magic I submit the following definition of the word "by" which has no place in this context, and further stipulate that the source has no definition for the word for. What for? I will tell you what for. Because for is not a word. Fir is a word. In Oregon that's what we use instead of the word for to avoid or enhance confusion! I reccomend it. ;)

by
/bī/
preposition

1. Identifying the agent performing an action.
2. Indicating the means of achieving something.
   "malaria can be controlled by attacking the parasite"

fir
/fər/
noun: fir;
plural noun: firs;
noun: fir tree;
plural noun: fir trees

An evergreen coniferous tree with upright cones and flat needle-shaped leaves, typically arranged in two rows. Firs are an important source of timber and resins.

Origin
Old Norse

Source: Google Dictionary

Comment: We can also just make if a sentence in English, it’s not about programming. I’ll extend the question, although your answer already gives insights.

Comment: Your answer talks about the difference between *from* and *for*. I might have missed it, but how does your answer distinguish the use of *by* and *for* in the OP's context?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “OP’s context”. I can only repeat that this is not about programming languages and keywords, this is about the difference of _by_ and _for_ used in a sentence like the one I posted in my answer to your other comment.

Comment: Be all that as it may, I am a programmer, and a writer of American Literature. I stand by my answer.

Comment: @idiotprovider thanks for the extended answer. It’s not about a single framework that exists or anything, it is a question I am asking myself very often as a non-native speaker while writing methods or similar. I want to write proper English and I want my methods to be readable, hence, it’s an English language question to me.

Comment: You're welcome. In one of the APIs I'm writing i have a function FindAllEntitiesByProject, the parameter is project_id. I would think if i had a function FindEntitiesForProject, it might take into account more aspects then just the identifier. What does your find_for function do?

Comment: In short, by and for, as defined in the English language are not suitably descriptive. What kind of specific programming actions are you addressing? And thank you for accepting my answer, it pleased me to have the opportunity to provide more detail.